# How to get Google search results count (total number of search results)

Tags: r

I used the following code to retrieve the total search results

[image: highlighted text I like to retrieve]

```
library(RCurl)
library(XML)

url <- "https://www.google.com/search?&q=cran&hl=en"

doc <- htmlTreeParse(getURL(url), useInternalNodes = TRUE)

nodes <- getNodeSet(doc, "//div[@id='result-stats']")
```

But I get the following output:

```
list()
attr(,"class")
[1] "XMLNodeSet"
```

where I like to get the number like **29,500,000**

Can anyone please help? It would be really great for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a valid user agent. Try this

```
ua <- "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.111 Safari/537.36"
doc <- htmlTreeParse(getURL(url, httpheader = list(`User-Agent` = ua)), useInternalNodes = TRUE)
```

Comment: Excellent! That's what I need. Thank you very much @ekoam. By the way, can you explain the user agent a bit?

Comment: Simply speaking, that is the tool you use to access the website server. The user agent above tells Google that "Hey, I'm using a Chrome browser". Some website servers, such as Google's, will block you if you don't specify a user agent or use an invalid one. @MeisterFremd